# How scikit learn implements the output layer

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, softmax

1. In scikit learn, how many neurons are in the output layer? As stated [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), you can only specify the hidden layer size and their neurons but nothing about the output layer, thus I am not sure how scikit learn implements the output layer.
2. Does it make sense to use `softmax` activation function for output layer having only a single neuron?

Comment: I guess it should be equal to `# of classes`, no?

Comment: @MaxU IF I have binary classes, does it mean that I should have two neurons in the output layers both having `softmax`?

Comment: if you have only one binary class (either `0` or `1`), then one output neuron should be enough. How many unique values has your `y` (target) data set and which shape does it have?

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for your response. My dataset has `10K` samples of `64` features. The class label is binary ( `1` or `-1`). Do you think the output activation function `softmax` would work here? I am thinking of `tanh` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test:

Setup:

```
In [227]: %paste
clf = MLPClassifier()

m = 10**3
n = 64

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(m, n))).add_prefix('x') \
       .assign(y=np.random.choice([-1,1], m))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(df.drop('y',1), df['y'], test_size=0.2, random_state=33)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[227]:
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
```

Number of outputs:

```
In [229]: clf.n_outputs_
Out[229]: 1
```

Number of layers:

```
In [228]: clf.n_layers_
Out[228]: 3
```

The number of iterations the solver has ran:

```
In [230]: clf.n_iter_
Out[230]: 60
```

---

Here is an excerpt of the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L273) where the activation function for the output layer will be chosen:

```
    # Output for regression
    if not is_classifier(self):
        self.out_activation_ = 'identity'
    # Output for multi class
    elif self._label_binarizer.y_type_ == 'multiclass':
        self.out_activation_ = 'softmax'
    # Output for binary class and multi-label
    else:
        self.out_activation_ = 'logistic'
```

**UPDATE:**  [MLPClassifier binarizes (in a one-vs-all fashion) labels internaly, so logistic regression should work well also with labels that are differ from `[0,1]`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L929):

```
    if not incremental:
        self._label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
        self._label_binarizer.fit(y)
        self.classes_ = self._label_binarizer.classes_
```

Comment: So `logistic` can work when the classes are `1` or `-1`? I thought it is only effective when the classes are binary i.e., `0` or `1` while others such as `tanh` work better for `1`,`-1`  classes as stated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function